# Fast Fourier Transform for non-trigoniometric bases

Tags: fourier-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials

The fast fourier transform allows decomposition into a sin/cos basis in $N \log(N)$ complexity. Can one generalize the algorithm (or the ideas used) to other basis, e.g. orthogonal polynomial bases such as Hermite, Legendre, Chebyshev,...? I have a special interest in Zernike polynomials as well.
If so, how?
If not, what is special about the sin/cos that separates it from the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
\exp((\omega_1+\omega_2)x)=\exp(\omega_1 x)\exp(\omega_2).
$$

This means that, if you think of the Fourier transform as expressing a function in the basis of exponential functions with different wave lengths, which I denote $b_{\omega}$, then you have the algebraic relation
$$
b_{\omega_1}b_{\omega_2}=b_{\omega_1+\omega_2}
$$
between elements of the basis.

BTW: For spherical harmonics, which are a basis of the square integrable functions on the two dimensional sphere, there exists a faster-than-standard algorithm as well (google Mohlenkamp, spherical harmonics)